# Very strange 500 Internal Server error

Tags: php, html

**EDIT:** going to the subdomain without adding index.php at the end of the address throws the error (and load parts of the html and prints parts of the javascript??). Going to the subdomain and adding the /index.php  will load just fine. I am in the mouth of madness. **END EDIT**

**EDIT 2:** It's been a long conversation, and I've got a lot of precious help from a lot of kind people, but the problem is still there. I decided to add a php redirection to itself, adding "index.php" in the address, when SERVER_URI doesn't find any "index.php". It's ugly. It's like pretending something works well. I don't like doing this. But I can't figure the problem... **END EDIT 2**

I have quite a big php file (mix of php, html, ajax, cURL...). Everything works just fine on mysite.com/app/index.php

When I move this to a newly created subdomain (I'm on shared hosting and already have other working subdomains), app.mysite.com, the whole thing throws an Internal Server error.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at
>   webmaster@veille.santeme.com to inform them of the time this error
>   occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The thing is... it also prints some html and javascript code, which looks random.

I tried to find the problem within the code and this became more and more insane.

The php is composed of functions, then html code with little php, then javascript/ajax/... at the end. I begun my testing by removing blocks from the html part. And got surprised.

I found an html block that solves the problem once removed:

```
<tr style="border-bottom: 1pt solid black;" onmouseover="this.className='over';" onmouseout="this.className='';">
                            <td style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; width: 10%;" class="marge_tableau"></td>
                            <td style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;" class="marge_tableau">a</td>
                            <td style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; text-align: center;" class="marge_tableau">a</td>
                            <td style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; text-align: center;" class="marge_tableau">a</td>
                            <td style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;" class="marge_tableau">a
                                    <?php /* Ici la lightbox cachée */ ?>
                                        <div style="display:none">
                                            <div id="lightbox_changer_password" class="shadow" style="padding:10px; background-color: #fff; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #000000;">
                                                <div style="width: 100%;">
                                                    Chang
                                                </div>

                                                <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">


                                                </div>
                                                <div style="clear: both;"></div><br>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php /* Fin de la lightbox */ ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

I even got to a point where removing part of an html string inside that particular div will remove the error!

`<div style="width: 100%;">
Chang
</div>` --> Error.

`<div style="width: 100%;">
Chan
</div>` --> Works.

No special chars or else. I really, really don't understand the link between those details and the subdomain thing and the internal error...

--> Can it be because of the total lenght of the script? I could post it here, but it's 1400 lines...

--> Nothing at all is displayed in the error_log. It is activated.

Comment: 500 response code is just a generic "something went wrong" sort of message. You need to check the server logs to find out what really happened.

Comment: I just added to the original question: there is nothing in the error_log. And it is activated.

Comment: At the begining of file, add, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: And if that doesn't work, make sure you're looking at the right error log: `var_dump(ini_get('error_log'));`

Comment: Pay attention to this: **Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**. Your server is trying to use an Error page to alert you about an error, and it can't find it. If it's Apache, make sure `httpd.conf` is pointing to the right path of these files (usually they are inside a dir called error)

Comment: It's worth noticing that it won't troubleshoot your issue, but will help you understand what is actually happening.

Comment: Don't forget to use the `@` symbol before someone's name if you want them to be notified. Like this: @rray

Comment: What do you mean "tried with no avail"? What was the **output** of the one I gave you?

Comment: @rray That didn't do anything.

Comment: @Mike The didn't do anything.

Comment: Create a new PHP file with the contents: `<?php var_dump(ini_get('error_log'));` and make sure the output matches the error log file that you were looking at.

Comment: The output matches. If I echo a unassigned php variable, both notice it.

I'm scratching my head. I really don't understand how modifying simple HTML in the script will cause or remove the Internal Server Error.

Comment: Execute this by command line if possible `php -l /path/to/your/file.php`

Comment: I'm on a shared server and don't really know how to access the Shell to execute commands.
Plus, the file works perfectly if i put the browser directly to it. It is broken only when I access it by the subdomain created in CPanel.
Since the error can be avoided by erasing some plain html code in the script, it doesn't seem to be a subdomain configuration error..

I am really confused.

Comment: I just did another test. app.mysite.com throws an error. app.mysite.com/index.php doesn't.

(all the .htaccess files are empty).

Comment: Did you check your server error log like it suggested?

Comment: I checked every possible error logs I could find. I even created errors to see them appear in the logs (and they appeared).

Comment: I just edit the original question with one more  revealing test. Adding /index.php at the end of the address solves the problem. But it is not a solution.
(without the index.php in the address, the server still locates it because parts of the html is printed after the « Internal Server Error » part... )

Comment: Don't you have an iframe in your code, or don't your curl queries get an internal server error  ?

Comment: maybe you copied and pasted that chang div? I got similar issues some time by some linebreaks i couldnt see... maybe if u delete all the white spaces and later then u make your own linebreaks?

Comment: @user1011278 I tried removing all the javascript code (including AJAX), and removing all cURL code. I'm left only with DB interactions and pure html. Still the Error.

Comment: @jpganz18 Can a blank space in pure html code throw an Internal Server Error?

Comment: @Martin it is not a blank space, thats why Im asking you to do that...

Comment: @Martin it is not a blank space, thats why Im asking you to do that...

Comment: @Martin it is not a blank space, thats why Im asking you to do that...

Comment: I can only suggest 1) free space, 2) server cache, 3) g symbol is a special char or special chars near, 4) charset, 5) browser cache, try to change your browser, 5) some strange size of file that crashes server, 6) broken file or broken hard drive on server, 7) the problem is linked to subdomain

Comment: @user1011278 
1) Possible, I'll look at it.*
2) Possible, I'll look at it*
3) I can erase the error if I take other parts of the code out. But maybe there is a special character repeating...
4) charset is UTF-8, DB too*
5) Tried FF and Chrome, same results, emptying the cache on each test
5-2) My favorite. Will look at it.*
6) Tried on two different shared hosting
7) Tried on two different shared hosting

* Still don't understand why the problem is solved by entering index.php in the address bar...

Comment: I talked to the support from the shareed hosting company, and I'm very sad.
They "kind of" fixed the problem with some .htaccess.
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]`
Now the internal server error is gone, but, instead, there is very strange code printed at the very end of the page (after my </html> tag, some of the previous code is re-printed in plain text).
I guess that is a symptom of the same problem that caused the previous internal server error... And again, it only happens when I don't put the 'index.php'.

Comment: Did you try to create a new index.php file and copy the content to it ?

Comment: @user1011278  I just tried that, and I see why you proposed it. That was a clever idea (in case of corrupted header in the textfile), but unfortunately it didn't work.

If someone wants to take a look, I renamed the file [index.txt so you can look at it](http://www.mmb.quebec/temp/index.txt) from a temp location. Keep in mind it works perfectly when I navigate directly to it; it's just broken when I don't add "index.php" at the end of the address.